# When is it safe to remove my installation USB?

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

I recently installed Ubuntu using a USB and was just wondering at what point can I remove the USB.

In other words, straight after the installation where it asks me to restart now, when I select restart now, can I remove my installation USB or do I need to leave plugged in until a later point in the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the USB Stick plugged in until the computer is shut down and restarts. Then you can unplug it to start from your HDD and not from the USB stick again.

Pull it out when the computer starts (BIOS Post; black screen, white letters) or shut the computer down and pull it out -- this way you're safe.